# Access a method in same project but different package

Tags: java

Is it possible to access a method in different package but same project without making the method public or inheritance? I'm looking for something similar to friendly assemblies in C#.

Comment: No,, it is not.

Comment: You can use reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to access a method in different package but same project without making the method public or inheritance?

Sortof, yes - [you can use reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string) to get the method that you're after, call `setAccessible(true)` on the method to suppress the access checks, then invoke it from wherever you like.

But...

> I'm looking for something similar to friendly assemblies in C#.

This isn't it, a similar feature simply doesn't exist in the Java language. The above reflection trick should really be treated as nothing more than a hack, and certainly not something you'd want to use in production code unless there really was *no other feasible option*.